# Calculate total score and categorize it based on input

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, reactive, calc

I'm trying to create an application for the SLE disease scoring system, in which each symptom is represented by a different number,

The total of symptom scores will be divided into a range of scores to determine disease activity.

Here is the code that I'm trying to write, but I haven't been able to figure out what the problem is that is keeping this program from running.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                       c("Neurological disorder" = "neu",
                         "Kidney disorder" = "gin",
                         "Vasculitis" = "vas",
                         "Haemolysis/ Thrombositopenia" = "hem",
                         "Myositis" = "mio",
                         "Artritis" = "art",
                         "Mucocutaneous disorder" = "muc",
                         "Serositis" = "ser",
                         "Fever/ Fatique" = "fev",
                         "Leukopenia/ Lhymphopenia" = "leu"
                         )),
    textOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    
    output$data <- reactive({
        input$neu <-  8
        input$gin <- 6
        input$vas <- 4
        input$hem <- 3
        input$mio <- 3
        input$art <- 2
        input$mio <- 2
        input$ser <- 2
        input$fev <- 1
        input$leu <- 1
        
    
        total <- input$neu + input$gin + input$vas + input$hem + input$mio +  
            input$art + input$mio + input$ser + input$fev + input$fev + input$leu
        
        if (total <= 2) {"Mild disease activity"}
        else if (total > 2 && < 5) {"Moderate disease activity"}
        else if (total >= 5){"Severe disease activity"}
        })
}

shinyApp (ui, server)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess you meant assign `=` or `<-` instead of comparison `==`

Comment: thank you for the correction, I've edited the example, but still can't run the application. can you show me where the error is?

Comment: The issue is also that these input are read only i.e. you cannot assign it to a value.

Comment: Also, your input name is 'variable' and not `neu` or anything else.  Those are the values stored

Comment: I think the solution posted should work.  Can you test it

Answer (score 0):

We may use a named vector to match and return the numbers based on the selection value of 'input$variable', get the `total` with just `sum` and use the same condition from OP's post to return the 'disease activity' values

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                     c("Neurological disorder" = "neu",
                       "Kidney disorder" = "gin",
                       "Vasculitis" = "vas",
                       "Haemolysis/ Thrombositopenia" = "hem",
                       "Myositis" = "mio",
                       "Artritis" = "art",
                       "Mucocutaneous disorder" = "muc",
                       "Serositis" = "ser",
                       "Fever/ Fatique" = "fev",
                       "Leukopenia/ Lhymphopenia" = "leu"
                     ), selected = "Leukopenia/ Lhymphopenia" = "leu"),
  textOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
output$data <- reactive({
    nm1 <- setNames(c(8, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), 
    c("neu", "gin", "vas", "hem", "mio", "art", "mio", "ser", "fev", "leu"))
    
   total <- sum(nm1[input$variable], na.rm = TRUE)
   if (total <= 2) {out <- "Mild disease activity"}
   else if (total > 2 && total < 5) {out <- "Moderate disease activity"}
   else if (total > 5) {out <- "Severe disease activity"}
   out
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have done something similar with a survey based on the SLEDAI-2K instrument for lupus severity.

We put all the manifestations (signs, symptoms, and lab results) in a data.frame, and included a second column with the associated number of points towards the overall score.

With that done, your `shiny` app can refer to the manifestations column for all the checkboxes. The score sum will then be the result of subsetting the data.frame based on selected checkboxes.

Finally, we used `cut` to take the numeric score sum and put into 3 categories of mild, moderate, and severe disease.

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(
  manifestation = c("Recent onset seizure", "Psychosis", "Organic brain syndrome",
    "Visual disturbance", "New onset sensory or motor neuropathy involving cranial nerves", 
    "Lupus headache", "New onset stroke", "Vasculitis", "Arthritis", "Myositis", "Heme-granular or RBC urinary casts",
    "Hematuria", "Proteinuria", "Pyuria", "Inflammatory-type rash", "Alopecia", "Oral or nasal mucosal ulcers",
    "Pleuritic chest pain with pleural rub/effusion or pleural thickening", "Pericarditis", "Low complement",
    "High DNA binding", "Temp >100.4 °F (38 °C)", "Platelets <100 x 10^9/L", "WBC <3 x 10^9/L"),
  score = c(rep(8, 8), rep(4, 6), rep(2, 7), rep(1, 3))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:", df$manifestation),
  textOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$data <- reactive({
    total <- sum(df[df$manifestation %in% input$variable, "score"])
    return(paste("Disease Severity:", cut(total, breaks = c(0, 2, 6, Inf), labels = c("Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))))
  })
}

shinyApp (ui, server)
```